# How can I avoid that a page break is added after a longtable?

Tags: longtable

I am writing a document that needs to have a long table, that will be autogenerated and may spawn several pages. I managed to implement it using longtable, but I found that, when the table ends, the rest of the page is blank and the next section starts in the next page. But, if the rest of the document is short enough to fit on the same page, it will not do a page break.

This is an example as minimal as I could get. I am working in some other implementation that I think will not trigger this issue, but I would prefer to use this one and, mostly, understand why this happens.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, landscape]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.17cm, bottom=3.17cm,
        left=3.17cm, right=2.54cm,
        headsep=0.2cm,headheight=50pt,heightrounded,
        footskip=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newmdenv[
  leftmargin=0pt,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt,
    innerrightmargin=0pt,
    innerleftmargin=0pt
]{siderules}

\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{C0C0C0}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

\begin{document}
\begin{siderules}
\begin{center}

\textbf{1. Section 1: } \\[\baselineskip]
\lipsum[1]

 \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\textbf{Section 2:} \\[\baselineskip]
The longtable starts a line below \\[\baselineskip]

\rowcolors{1}{grey}{white}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{longtable}{p{0.07\linewidth}  p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.1\linewidth} p{0.13\linewidth}}

\rowcolor[HTML]{343434} {\textcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\textbf{Issue ID}}} & { \textcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\textbf{Title}}} & {\textcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\textbf{Assignee}}} & {\textcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}{\textbf{Closed At (UTC)}}}    \\ 

 01    & This is a long line that whould wrap up inside the cell when it reaches the end of the available space & 2c \\ 
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\ 
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\ 
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\ 
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\ 
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    \\ 
  2a   & 2b    & 2c    &  2d    
\end{longtable} 

This line should start just below the table.

 \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\textbf{Section 3} \\[\baselineskip]

\lipsum[2]

 \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\textbf{Section 4} \\[\baselineskip]

\lipsum[3]

 \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\textbf{Section 5} \\[\baselineskip]

\lipsum[4]

\end{center}
\end{siderules}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing the sideruls fixes it.  Now the question is why.

Comment: @JohnKormylo since the output routine changes at that point I'm mildly surprised mdframed works at all (certainly never been tested)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Interesting. I need the vertical lines at the end, so if I cannot use long table and the siderules at the same time I will need to keep working on an alternative approach.

Comment: Since you seem to be putting everything inside a frame, why not use the showframe option of geometry, or use tikzpagenodes to outline the text area.